# Once role is assigned to Account Team Members send email?

Tags: workflow, account, email-alert, roles

Once role is assigned to Account team members we need to send email alert. Is it possible by workflow or any other means?

Answer (score 1):

**Process Builder is the best way to do this.**

The Process Builder is a workflow tool that helps you easily automate your business processes by providing a powerful and user-friendly graphical representation of your process as you build it. The Process Builder’s simple and powerful design allows you to:

1) Create your processes using a convenient layout with point-and-click efficiency.

2) Create your whole process in one place rather than using multiple workflow rules.

3) Create processes by collaborating with different teams in your business.

4) Stop using Apex code to automate simple tasks.

Comment: note IDEA - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfFWAA0 which suggests this isn't available for AccountTeamMember